# Phone font symbol

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, icons, symbols

Where can I find the phone font symbol -- the one you can see on the "End call" button on the iPhone -- to put it into a `UILabel` into XCode 4.2 ?

I've searched Apple Symbol, Zapf Dingbats and Wingdings and I didn't find it. And Cairo does not seem to be present anymore on the Macintosh or in Xcode.

**EDIT :** 
Can someone having a jailbroken phone confirm if it's an image as said by Noah ?

Comment: @DA : Not 100% sure but as it follows the text when localized, I guess it is... I can't imagine they have wroten by hand each pixel position of the image for each localization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not a font symbol; you’ll have to use an image. You can either (1) try recreating the Apple-style one in your preferred image editor or (2) dig through a jailbroken phone’s filesystem (inside `Phone.app` would be a good place to look) for the actual PNG itself.

Comment: Ouchh... You sure ? If it's not a font symbol, how did they manage to add it to the left of the text ?

Comment: @Oliver who tells you, that the text isn't a picture as-well?

Comment: @ vikingosegundo : Nobody  :-)  It's just a feeling that it would be really easier to localize a string than making different images for each localisations. That would lead to a "huge" binary and efforts for a little benefit.